# Recording data on a daily basis onto Excel using DataFrames

Tags: excel, database, pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

Good morning, right now I'm working on a RPi project that captures some data every second and translates it to a numerical figure. I want the RPi to save this number/time data to an excel file, and I also want this file to be accessible, with the data being "graph-able" depending on user input (i.e. user wants data from past 3 days > output graph of data from past 3 days). I understand that this can be divided into two parts: read and save data(1) and pull and graph data(2). For this question I would like to focus on (1).

For reading data from the sensor and saving it to an excel file that acts as a database, I was thinking of using pandas' DataFrame. Why, you may ask. I am basing my code on a previous code left by a predecessor, and it already has similar read/write code. However the scale is largely different (~50 entries vs ~38000 entries).

I was thinking of recording the data as:

[Basic Text Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inGdc.jpg)
[Data in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x1C4.jpg)

As you can see, if there is data for every second, I would end up with 86400 entries for one single day.

Write now, my code for saving this data is as follows. I made a class for the data to be saved, which has the variables:

```
class ShiftDataSet:

def __init__(self):
    self.effDataList = []
    self.timeDataList = []
    self.dateTimeToday = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.date = self.dateTimeToday.strftime("%y%b%d")#str
    #%y is year without century, %b is month abbv, %d is day of month
```

This data is then (attempted) to be recorded into a dataframe, then into an excel file as follows:

```
def saveToDf(self):
    dataToSave = {self.date : self.effDataList}
    #dictionary of data to save. effDataList is the list of 1's and 0's as read by the second.

    dfToSave = pd.DataFrame(dataToSave, index=self.timeDataList)
    #create DataFrame to save as Excel, using timeDataList as index. timeDataList is a str list of the second the recording is taken

    print("Attempting to save data")

    #code to combine dfToSave with old df record
    oldDf = pd.read_excel("/home/pi/Sensor/FS Days/Shift Record Template.xlsx")
    #oldDf is the database template, structured the same way like the "Data in Excel" image above

    result = dfToSave.combine_first(oldDf)
    #combine new dataframe of new data with template database

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("/home/pi/Sensor/FS Days/Shift Record Template.xlsx")
    result.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet 1')

    writer.save()
    print("Save Complete")

    return
```

I modeled this code based on my predecessor's code for smaller scale recordings. Running this code however, I run into the problem of the data not being written properly into the excel file, which ends up as follows:
[Messed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m9TM.jpg)

So my questions are:
1) How can I record the data as taken per second into the proper "seconds" index?
2) Would it be better to record and save data every second, or pool it into a larger list then save once or twice during the day?
3) Is pandas DataFrame the best solution for what I want to do, or are there better methods out there?

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Just like you defined the index for `dfToSave`, you have to do the same when you `read_excel()`.

2) This depends on your hardware mostly I guess; it is difficult to make this judgement without any background info.

3) I would use pandas as well but this doesn't mean it's the best way. You could look at other excel libraries for Python I guess...

Comment: 1) Thank you very much for the tip! That would mean adding idex_col=0 to the excel read, yes? Also it seems like when pandas read the DataFrame, it reparses the indeces back to int (052930 becomes 52930), so I added a letter to the time stamps.  

2) Hardware is a Raspberry Pi 3B+. I noticed that it only always uses a single core though..  

3) I'll stick with pandas then if that's what someone with more experience would use..